# Inconsistent space above caption with \fbox

Tags: spacing, captions

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{4cm}{4cm}
    \caption{A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{%
        \rule{4cm}{4cm}%
    }%
    \caption{B}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\fboxsep}{30pt}%
    \fbox{%
        \rule{4cm}{4cm}%
    }%
    \caption{C}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The vertical space above the captions of A and B are equal, the space above the caption of C is smaller. Why? Is this behavior intended?

When I load the <s>`float`</s> `caption` package, the spaces above all captions are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for most spaces in TeX, the spacing is mostly defined via baseline to baseline spacing so above A you have

```
....\glue 10.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
```

which is 10pt from the above caption space and 5.17pt  to add to the height of A to make a baseline space

B is similar

```
....\glue 10.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.7667
```

But because of the large `\fboxsep` the `\fbox` has large depth (the images have zero depth) so baseline spacing can not be achieved, and in that case TeX uses lineskip so above C you get

```
....\glue 10.0
....\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
```